# SQL Procedure incorrectly checks if value exists

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, data-comparison

I'm building a Windows Forms Application with a connection to an SQL Database.
On start-up of my app, it will send some queries to the database to compare values:

[image: Query list]

Here is the code that generates the query:

```
    private void CreateInsertQuery(DirectoryInfo source, string Printer)
    {
         foreach (FileInfo file in source.GetFiles())
        {
            queries.Add("EXECUTE sqlp_UpdateInsertFiles '"+ file.Name +"', '" + Printer + "'"); 
        }
         foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in source.GetDirectories())
        {
            queries.Add("EXECUTE sqlp_UpdateInsertFiles '" + folder.Name + "', '" + Printer + "'");
            CreateInsertQuery(folder, Printer); 
        }
    }
```

`queries` is a public List.

This is the code that sends the query to the db:

```
   public bool InsertQueries()
    {
        con.Open(); 
        using(OleDbTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd;
                foreach (string query in queries)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con, trans);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        if (ex.HResult != -2147217873)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
                trans.Commit();
                con.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                trans.Rollback();
                con.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

In my SQL database, I've created a stored procedure that gets called when the database receives the query:

```
    AS
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
            BEGIN TRY
                IF EXISTS
                   (SELECT TOP 1 fName, Printer
                    FROM   dbo.FileTranslation
                    WHERE  fName = @fName AND Printer = @Printer)
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE dbo.FileTranslation
                        SET fName = @fName, Printer = @Printer
                END;
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO dbo.FileTranslation(fName, Printer) VALUES (@fName, @Printer);
                END;
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
            
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                BEGIN
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
                END
            END CATCH
        END;
GO
```

When I run my application on an empty database, then the values will get added without any problem:

[image: DataBase's table: first start-up].

I also do not get any error occurrences. It's only when I start my application for a second time, that the first 2 query's do not get checked on the IF EXISTS. Because it is still inserting the data into my database, 5x to be exact.

[image: Database filled with duplicates].

Which is weird as there are only 2 queries containing the data, but it gets executed every time.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: **WARNING:** The image of your code shows that your application is wide open to injection attacks. **Never** inject unsanitised values into your SQL statements. *Parametrise* your statements.

Comment: Is this as intended? `UPDATE dbo.FileTranslation SET fName = @fName, Printer = @Printer -- MISSING WHERE???????`

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern

Comment: When an error occurs in your stored procedure, you eat the error. The caller of the procedure has NO IDEA the logic failed.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the `id` column is an sql identity column, right?
Because the first continous 7 entries are all the same I think your app is started on multiple threads which at the beginning are executing head-by-head but later their execution diverges maybe because of extra time of exception handling block. That's why only the first records are multiplied.

The problem is that your stored procedure isn't thread-safe. No locks placed on `dbo.FileTranslation` table by the `IF EXISTS(SELECT ...` which in parallel execution may result in situation where multiple executing stored procedures find the required record unexisting and will continue with the `INSERT` branch.

Applying the answers from https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187405/sql-server-concurrent-inserts-and-deletes thread this may work for you:

```sql
...
IF EXISTS
   (SELECT TOP 1 fName, Printer
    FROM   dbo.FileTranslation WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
    WHERE  fName = @fName AND Printer = @Printer)
...
```

PS: Not related to your question but take care about @Lamu's comment on SQL injection and use `try...finally` or `using` pattern for you `conn` handling!

Comment: Thanks, using a combination of the WHERE clause on my update and using WITH (UPDLOCK,SERIALIZABLE)